# pass on TouchEvents to underlying application

Tags: android, xamarin

I have created a floating window on top of everything by adding it to the windowManager.AddView( myView)
this works well and shows the window on top of everything.

In some cases i would like to pass Touch events on to any of the the underlying apps/OS.

Is this possible ?

- I tried sending the MotionEvent to Instrumentation,
- I tried setting the TouchEventArgs.Handled to false

  ```
  private void MyTouchHandler(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
  {
      if( dayIsMonday)
      {
          // method 1
          Thread t = new Thread(() =>
          {
              Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
              inst.SendPointerSync(e.Event);
          });
          t.IsBackground = true;
          t.Start();

          // method 2
          e.Handled = false;
      }
      else
      {
          moveMyWindow();
          e.Handled = true;
      }
  }
  ```

but neither seem to do anything.

kind regards,
tom

Comment: What do you mean by "to any of the the underlying apps"? Do you want send messages to OTHER apps or your app?

Comment: not so much directly to other apps, bit indirectly . just want to pass the 'mouse/touch/ message through to whatever the OS decides is below it..

Comment: AFAIK there is no "below" while your app is in the foreground. What do you expect to happen if you could do that? Touch happens on you "desktop"? What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the window that is floating on top is 'semi' transparent.. i only want something to happen when they click on a particular location on the window.. other than that i would like it to be 'invisible' to sight and touch.. so yes, if the 'desktop' is below it then the click should be handled by the desktop, and if another app is below the click location it should be handled by the other app.

when i don't handle a mouse click in windows/OSX/X app the OS, just passes it to the window stack to the next window down in the z-order